# How can i access shared preferences from another view

Tags: android, eclipse, sharedpreferences

I have following code in settings.java:

```
public static int numberOfQuestions = 0;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);    

        pref = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_SETTINGS, 0);    

        final RadioGroup rg_numberOfQuestions = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroupQuestions);        
        rg_numberOfQuestions.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);      
        RadioButton rbtn = ((RadioButton) rg_numberOfQuestions.findViewById(pref.getInt("NQ", 0)));
        if(rbtn!=null)
            rbtn.setChecked(true);
}

public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rg, int i) {                        
        switch (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId())
        {
        case R.id.rb_0to10:
            numbersBetween = 10;        
            break;

        case R.id.rb_0to25:
            numbersBetween = 25;        
            break;

        case R.id.rb_0to50:
            numbersBetween = 50;
            break;
        }
        if(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.rb_0to10 || rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.rb_0to25 || rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == R.id.rb_0to50)
        {
            savePref("NB", rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        }
     }
```

This is code to save and access preference:

```
    private void savePref(String key, int value) {
        pref = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_SETTINGS, 0);
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);      
        editor.commit();
    }

    private void savePref(String key, Boolean value) {
        pref = getSharedPreferences(Constants.PREF_SETTINGS, 0);
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);      
        editor.commit();
    }   
}
```

If i am in settings numberOfQuestions  variable gets updated and it works fine in my other view called main.java. But lets say i open main.java directly and not open setting first numberOfQuestions does not have right value. Is there easier way to transfer shared preference value to other view? Or do i need to write all cases in main.java also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special, you can use the same shared preferences from each part of your app in the same way.

You can move the methods to access shared preferences to:

- a parent class for all your activities
- a static methods in a helper class (you would have to pass context as parameter in this case and be careful not to create a reference to this context to avoid memory leaks).

Comment: I updated my question. In particular i need to use one variable any idea what is best way to do that?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Not sure what exactly you mean.

Comment: I am trying to get numberOfQuestions value in main.java but if settings.java is opened first i dont get the right value. Is there a better way to get that value in main.java?

Comment: @Szymon- In above code i am creating a static variable called numberOfQuestions. Which i am accessing from main. java. But numberOfQuestions only gets updated if user opens settings.java file first.

Comment: Ah, ok. Don't use static variables for that. Just read from shared preferences in every activity - this makes it easier for you if any activity can be started first. You can put the code to read into a helper class to a static method.

Comment: But my question is i can access shared preferences from main.java but problem is than i will have to create switch statement in main.java also right? Is there a better way to do this to avoid that?

Comment: that switch statement is updating numberOfQuestions according to the shared preferences. My question is how can i access those values from another view.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41067/discussion-between-szymon-and-noviceme)

Comment: Click on the chat link above

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
`numberOfQuestions = getSharedPreferences(Constants.NUM_OF_QUESTIONS, 0);`
to initialize its value. then access it anywhere in your application

Comment: Where will i save these preference what you are accessing above? I am confused?

Comment: the preference value will be saved in xml file located in your application data directory. The value can be accessed globally in your application wherever you use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).